# How to search a text in the files under a folder in Windows operating system

Tags: windows, file, search, text, directory

In my **windows** machine I have a folder with multiple folders and multiple files under each folders **different types of files**. 
**Example**: *.txt, .properties, .xml, .sh, .bat etc...*

Now I want to identify the presence of a particular text in the files within the folder.

**For Example** : I want to Identify all the files which contains the word

> "au.com.galaxy"

Is there any shortcut way to do it without opening and searching in each file ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
findstr /snipr "au\.com\.galaxy" *.*
```

Comment: For most answers it is a good idea to add an explanation to show how the code works, this helps other people with less programming experience understand what the code does.

Comment: Have to run the command in the command prompt. It will list out all the files which contains the text.